# depthimage_to_laserscan launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i create a launch file that convert depthimage to laserscan:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="camera"  default="camera"/>
    <arg name="publish_tf" default="true"/>
    <group if="$(arg scan_processing)">
        <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="depthimage_to_laserscan" args="load depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet $(arg camera)/$(arg camera)_nodelet_manager">
        <param name="scan_height" value="10"/>
        <param name="output_frame_id" value="/$(arg camera)_depth_frame"/>
        <param name="range_min" value="0.45"/>
        <remap from="image" to="$(arg camera)/$(arg depth)/image_raw"/>
        <remap from="scan" to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
    </group>   
</launch>
```

when i run: `roslaunch fake_laser_pkg start_laser.launch`, i receive this error:

> [start_laser.launch] is neither a
> launch file in package
> [fake_laser_pkg] nor is
> [fake_laser_pkg] a launch file name
> The traceback for the exception was
> written to the log file
> what can i do please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235099/depthimage_to_laserscan-launch/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-05-24**:
Where did you put the launch file?

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-05-24**:
in ==> catkin_ws/src/fake_laser_pkg/launch/start_laser.launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that calling your node is correct? I think it should be something like this:

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="depthimage_to_laserscan_loader" args="load depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet $(arg manager)">
```

Did you source the `setup.bash` file? if not try executing:

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2016-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-05-24**:
thank you very much

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-05-24**:
Welcome!
Mark it as correct if it is the right answer

**Comment by [khasreto](https://answers.ros.org/users/38724/khasreto/) on 2018-11-27**:
i have error that launch requires the 'scan_processing' arg to be set